# Como controlar sessão de uma aplicação web em diferentes abas do navegador?

Tags: aplicação-web, session

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação web e utilizando sessão no servidor para controle de acesso a aplicação, essa sessão deve ser encerrada quando o usuário fizer logout da aplicação, quando fechar todas as abas da mesma ou quando ele fechar o navegador.

Gostaria de saber, quais as melhores práticas para esse tipo de controle?

Comment: Por que está utilizando sessão? Para o seu caso Formsauthentication  é uma boa.

Comment: Porque utilizamos a tecnologia Intersystems Caché e seu framework web CSP (Caché Server Pages), assim todo o controle de acesso dos usuário foi desenvolvido em cima dos recursos de sessão que ele dispõe.

Comment: Essa tecnologia foi criada para esse tipo de coisa, controle de usuários por sessão não parece legal.

Comment: No .NET, costumo guardar a informação de Autorização em Cookie codificado. Você pode definir data de expiração, e de tempos em tempos renovar/reescrever o Cookie. Você pode fazer uma programação orientada a Eventos. O evento de click do botão de Logout, o evento de fechamento de Aba e o evento de fechamento do Browser, todos podem reescrever ou colocar uma validade no passado do Cookie, assim, voce condiciona seu código a forçar a entrada de tela de login toda a vez que o cookie estiver expirado. Para garantir o mínimo de segurança, considere utilizar o Cookie com valores codificados.

Comment: Na sua opinião qual seria a melhor abordagem?

Comment: Você não especificou a linguagem que você esta trabalhando, mas no PHP quando você usa as SESSIONS assim que você apaga o navegador elas se destroem porem pode utilizar a session_destroy() no logout. Usando o cookie mesmo fechando o navegador o usuário continuar logado, o que ao meu ver não é muito seguro dependendo da aplicação! muito utilizado em carrinhos de compra.